# How to get a value from a datatable with row values be items of a combobox in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

How do you get a value from the datatable(not a datagrid) through a combobox? The lessonype column of the datatable are all items of a combobox. What if i want to get the rate of lessontype “guitar”?

Example

```
lessontype |  Rate

-----------+--------

 Piano     |  100

 Guitar    |  50

 Violin    |  200

Trumpet    |  150
```

Comment: Please provide some code you've been working on.

Comment: I've been trying this code but it provides an error saying "Cannot find column[rate].

MyCode:
DataRow[] filteredRows = dt.Select(string.Format("{0} LIKE '%{1}%'", rate, lessons.Text));

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVVM, you can bind the ComboBox to a property in your ViewModel

XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedIndex="{Binding MyIndex}" />
```

ViewModel (must implement the INotifyPropertychanged interface):

```
    private int _myList;
    public List<YourType> MyList
    {
        get { return _myList; }
        set
        {
            _myList = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("MyList");
        }
    }
    private int _myIndex;
    public int MyIndex 
    {
        get { return _myIndex; }
        set
        {
            _myIndex= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("MyIndex");
        }
    }
```

Whenever you want to know which item in the ComboBox the user has selected, you use MyList[MyIndex].WhateverIsStoredHere to get the item in the ComboBox.

Comment: I've been trying this code but it provides an error saying "Cannot find column[rate]. 

MyCode: 

DataRow[] filteredRows = dt.Select(string.Format("{0} LIKE '%{1}%'", rate, lessons.Text));

Comment: If the List keeps changing, then it should also use the NotifyPropertychanged method.
Let me know if it works :)

Comment: What list? lessons is the name of the combobox. so whatever item i choose , it is already stored in the lessons.text. Am i right about this? Sorry, just a newbie here.

Comment: OK, I am not sure if I understood the question right then.
Could you provide more code, where you have initialized your DataTable, and where you try to get items from it?